# Z3: Find if variable is multiple of some other number

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I would like to create a constraint that makes sure that a Real value is quantized to some tick value.

```
TICK = 0.5
x = Real('x')
solve(x % TICK == 0)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work with Real numbers (it works with Int and FP).
Another solution that I thought of was to create a set of valid numbers and check whether the number is part of the set, however the set would need to be really big.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: What library is Real() from?

Comment: @Danielme it's from z3

Comment: I can only compile online so I cannot test this library, but looking at the [documentation](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm) % is a supported operator UREM (unsigned remainder). Are you getting an error or is it not behaving like you expect?

Comment: There is no remainder of a real-numbered division, so `%` doesn't make sense. You'd have to convert your real to an integer first and that is also where you specify the quantization levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Christoph mentioned, computing the modulus of a real-number isn't really meaningful. But your question is still valid: You're asking if `x` is an integer multiple of `TICK`. You can do this as follows:

```py
from z3 import *

TICK = 0.5
x = Real('x')
k = Int('k')
solve(x == 1,   ToReal(k) * TICK == x)
solve(x == 1.2, ToReal(k) * TICK == x)
```

This prints:

```
[k = 2, x = 1]
no solution
```

Note that unless `x` is a constant, this'll lead to a mixed integer-real arithmetic, and it might give rise to non-linear constraints. This can make it hard for the solver to answer your query, i.e., it can return `unknown` or take too long to respond. It all depends on what other constraints you have on `x`.